# get touch section (triangle) of a UIIMageView (circle) with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a circle (UIImage) divided into four sections (triangles).
Also I know tree points of the sections, center, upper left and upper right.

How can i calculate which sections is touched with UITapGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `CGPathRef` of each of your shapes, you can call `CGPathContainsPoint` with the value returned by your gesture recognizer’s `-locationInView:` on each of the paths until you find the one you tapped.

Alternatively, you can split the image into four separate images and set them as the images of four separate buttons with their own target/action handlers.